# What is the difference between true? and boolean

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, what is the difference between the `true?` function and the `boolean` function?

I see from the source code that a difference does exist (meta-information removed):

```
(defn boolean [x] (clojure.lang.RT/booleanCast x))
(defn true? [x] (clojure.lang.Util/identical x true))
```

Comment: Truthiness (coercion to boolean values) is covered in the official documentation for [`if`](http://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#if), and the specific behaviors of [`true?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/true_q) and [`boolean`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/boolean) are covered on ClojureDocs.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the source code, `true?` returns `true` if the value is **identical to `true`**. `boolean` returns `true` if the value is merely **truthy** (all values except `false` and `nil`).

```
=> (map true? [true 0 1 :a])
(true false false false)
=> (map boolean [true 0 1 :a])
(true true true true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `boolean` is a type cast to Clojure's boolean values `true` or `false`. It works according to the rules of truthiness as exercised by `if` and all its progeny: `nil` and `false` act false; everything else acts true.

You could define it as

```
(defn boolean [x]
  (case x
    (nil false) false
    true))
```

Function `true?` determines whether the argument is the Clojure value `true`. You could define it as

```
(defn true? [x] (identical? true x))
```

Thus `(boolean :whatever)` is `true`, whereas `(true? :whatever)` is `false`.

---

There are some nasties lurking under the surface, due to Java allowing new 
`Boolean` objects to be created. More later.